# Cannot place Collision Detection debug rectangle over game sprites

Tags: c++, youtube, collision-detection, sdl-2

I am following along Let's Make An RPG (C++/SDL2) - Tutorials on Youtube and am stuck on Let's Make an RPG (C++/SDL2) - Part 35 Continuation on Collision (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLu6g2S3Ta0&list=PLHM_A02NtaaVey-4Ezh7p6bbOsv-DKA-0).

I am trying to place a transparent rectangle over all sprites to debug collision detection. I am not getting any errors so there is no one piece of code I can show you.

Can someone please shed some light on where I went wrong. I'm very new to C++ but I'm not giving up. Thank you for your time. I'm genuinely grateful.

**This is the code for both the header and cpp file of the Collision Rectangle**

```
#include "CollisionRectangle.h"

CollisionRectangle::CollisionRectangle()
{
    OffsetX = 0;
    OffsetY = 0;
    SetRectangle(0,0,0,0);
}

CollisionRectangle::CollisionRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{

    OffsetX = x;
    OffsetY = y;
    SetRectangle(0,0,w,h);
}

CollisionRectangle::~CollisionRectangle()
{
    //dtor
}

void CollisionRectangle::SetRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    CollisionRect.x = x + OffsetY;
    CollisionRect.y = y + OffsetY;
    CollisionRect.w = w;
    CollisionRect.h = h;
}

//header
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

class CollisionRectangle
{
    public:
        CollisionRectangle();
        CollisionRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h);
        ~CollisionRectangle(void);

        void SetRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h);

        SDL_Rect GetRectangle(){ return CollisionRect; }

        void setX(int x){ CollisionRect.x = x + OffsetX; }


        void setY(int y){ CollisionRect.y = y + OffsetY; }

    private:
        int OffsetX;
        int OffsetY;
        SDL_Rect CollisionRect;
};
```

**This is the code for the both the header and the cpp file of Sprites**

```
#include "Sprite.h"

Sprite::Sprite(SDL_Renderer* passed_renderer, std::string FilePath, int x, int y, int     w, int h, float *passed_CameraX, float *passed_CameraY, CollisionRectangle passed_CollisionRect)
{
    CollisionRect = passed_CollisionRect;
    renderer = passed_renderer;

    CollisionSDL_Rect = CollisionRect.GetRectangle();

    image = NULL;
    image = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, FilePath.c_str());

    if (image == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't load " << FilePath.c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    CollisionImage = NULL;
    CollisionImage = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "Data/DebugImages/DebugBox.png");

    if (CollisionImage == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't load " << "CollisionImage" << std::endl;
    }

    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    rect.w = w;
    rect.h = h;

    SDL_QueryTexture(image,NULL,NULL, &img_width, &img_height);

    crop.x = 0;
    crop.y = 0;
    crop.w = img_width;
    crop.h = img_height;

    X_pos = x;
    Y_pos = y;

    Origin_X = 0;
    Origin_Y = 0;

    CurrentFrame = 0;

    Amount_Frame_X = 0;
    Amount_Frame_Y = 0;


    CameraX = passed_CameraX;
    CameraY = passed_CameraY;
    Camera.x = rect.x + *CameraX;
    Camera.y = rect.y + *CameraY;
    Camera.w = rect.w;
    Camera.h = rect.h;
}

void Sprite::DrawSteady()
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,image, &crop, &rect);
}

void Sprite::Draw()
{


    Camera.x = rect.x + *CameraX;
    Camera.y = rect.y + *CameraY;

    CollisionRect.setX(rect.x + *CameraX);
    CollisionRect.setY(rect.y + *CameraY);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,image, &crop, &Camera);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,CollisionImage, NULL, &CollisionSDL_Rect);
}


void Sprite::SetUpAnimation(int passed_Amount_X, int passed_Amount_Y)
{
    Amount_Frame_X = passed_Amount_X;
    Amount_Frame_Y = passed_Amount_Y;
}

void Sprite::PlayAnimation(int BeginFrame, int EndFrame, int Row, float Speed)
{
    if (animationDelay+Speed < SDL_GetTicks())
    {
        if (EndFrame <= CurrentFrame)
            CurrentFrame = BeginFrame;
        else
            CurrentFrame++;

        crop.x = CurrentFrame * (img_width/Amount_Frame_X);
        crop.y = Row * (img_height/Amount_Frame_Y);
        crop.w = img_width/Amount_Frame_X;
        crop.h = img_height/Amount_Frame_Y;
        animationDelay = SDL_GetTicks();
    }
}

Sprite::~Sprite()
{
    SDL_DestroyTexture(image);
}

void Sprite::SetX(float X)
{
    X_pos = X;
    rect.x = int(X_pos - Origin_X);
}

void Sprite::SetY(float Y)
{
    Y_pos = Y;
    rect.y = int(Y_pos - Origin_Y);
}

void Sprite::SetPosition(float X, float Y)
{
     X_pos = X;
     Y_pos = Y;
    rect.x = int(X_pos - Origin_X);
    rect.y = int(Y_pos - Origin_Y);
}

float Sprite::getX()
{
    return X_pos;

}

float Sprite::getY()
{
    return Y_pos;
}

void Sprite::SetOrigin(float X, float Y)
{
    Origin_X = X;
    Origin_Y = Y;
    SetPosition(getX(),getY());
}

void Sprite::SetWidth(int W)
{
    rect.w = W;
}

void Sprite::SetHeight(int H)
{
    rect.h = H;
}

int Sprite::GetWidth()
{
   return rect.w;
}

int Sprite::GetHeight()
{
   return rect.h;
}

//header

#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SDL_Setup.h"
#include "CollisionRectangle.h"


class Sprite
{
    public:
    Sprite(SDL_Renderer* passed_renderer, std::string FilePath, int x, int y, int w, int h, float *CameraX, float *CameraY, CollisionRectangle passed_CollisionRect);
    ~Sprite();

    void Draw();
    void DrawSteady();

    void SetX(float X);
    void SetY(float Y);
    void SetPosition(float X, float Y);

    float getX();
    float getY();

    void SetOrigin(float X, float Y);

    int GetWidth();
    int GetHeight();

    void SetHeight(int H);
    void SetWidth(int W);

    void PlayAnimation(int BeginFrame, int EndFrame, int Row, float Speed);
    void SetUpAnimation(int passed_Amount_X, int passed_Amount_Y);


    private:
    CollisionRectangle CollisionRect;

    SDL_Rect Camera;
    SDL_Rect CollisionSDL_Rect;

    float *CameraX;
    float *CameraY;

    float Origin_X;
    float Origin_Y;
    float X_pos;
    float Y_pos;

    SDL_Texture* image;
    SDL_Texture* CollisionImage;

    SDL_Rect rect;
    SDL_Rect crop;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

    int img_width;
    int img_height;
    int CurrentFrame;
    int animationDelay;

    int Amount_Frame_X;
    int Amount_Frame_Y;
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are the rects not being display? Hard to help if we don't know that the issue. But how about using SDL_RenderDrawRect()? https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawRect

Comment: Without the relevant information regarding what the problem is no-one will be able to help you barring a miracle.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The problem is I want to place a transparent rectangle on all my sprites to help in the creation of collision detection. My problem is that all rectangles just stay in the top left corner of the screen. I am getting no errors. The code just won't do what it is supposed to. All of the code was taken down exactly from the youtube video linked above. His works, mine doesn't. Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: @alienfrenZy You are setting the values x,y,w,h for `SDL_Rect rect;` which is a member of the Sprite class and you are assigning it a `CollisionRectangle CollisionRect;` but you never set the x,y,w,h for the 'CollisionRectangle CollisionRect;'

Comment: @alienfrenZy apologies yes you appear to be. Your naming convention makes things a bit unclear having some variables named with uppercase and others not (they can be confused with methods). Is there any way you could post your project on github or something?